# minimum length video for tracking milestones with sitecatalysts

Tags: video, adobe-analytics

We are tracking videos with the media plugin and have configured it to track events at start, 25%, 50%, 75% and 100%. This works fine for our longer videos (2+ minutes), but short videos (<30s) are only sending start and 100%. Can't find any documentation on this nor has the PS been helpful. Anyone run into a similar issue?

EDIT: With the following params set

```
s.Media.autoTrack=false;
s.Media.trackWhilePlaying=true;
s.Media.trackVars="events,prop27,eVar23,eVar24,eVar25,eVar26";
s.Media.trackEvents="event21,event22,event23,event24,event25,event26,event27";
s.Media.trackMilestones="25,50,75";
s.Media.segmentByMilestones = true;
s.Media.trackUsingContextData = true;
```

Comment: Do you have s.Media.trackSeconds defined in your implementation? If so, what is it set to?

Comment: No. I've added that params set to my question.

Comment: If you're using trackUsingContextData, you will also want to include contextDataMapping and have gone through the setup wizard in SiteCatalyst to properly map the variables on both ends.

Comment: So it turns out our short videos were using a different player and not reporting events correctly. This wasn't a SiteCat issue.